# Запрос на поиск максимальных значений в группе Access

Tags: sql, запрос, access, ms-access

Есть условная таблица:

| участок | сектор | кол-во квадратов | кол-во кругов |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1-2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2-1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2-2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2-3 | 1 | 3 |

Мне необходимо написать запрос на выборку максимальных значений(круги, квадраты) по группе(участок), что бы в итоге вывод был следующим:

| участок | сектор | MAX(кол-во квадратов) | MAX(кол-во кругов) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2-2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2-3 | 1 | 3 |

но я упираюсь в проблему того что значение "сектора" всегда уникально, и я получаю вывод максимальных значений для сектора но не для группы.

Прошу Вас помочь мне с этим или направить в нужное русло

Comment: то есть вам не сам максимум надо найти, а строки в которых этим максимумы встречаются? Обычно в таком случае можно к основной таблице приджойнить подзапрос в поиском этих максимумов по группам и в условии джойна будет группа и значения масимумов. но тут все равно кажется несколько сложнее ситуация

Comment: возможно сделать две выборки на каждый столбец и потом объединить уже результаты.

Comment: @teran, неожиданно, но мы с Вами из одного города:) Я пытался так сделать но потом не обнаружил способа объединить, так как нет столбца по которому джоин сделать можно. Если я в запрос по поиску максимума даже в одном столбце, включаю номер сектора. то получаю полный список

Comment: бывает. судя по тому что ваша задача больше смахивает на какую нибудь  лабораторную работу по курсу СУБД, то мы еще мб и находимся в одном учебном заведении

Comment: @teran,  к сожалению коллеги озадачили. ПетрГУ уже окончил, в далёком 2016м

Answer (score 2):

Будет что-то типа

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table t1,
     ( SELECT t2.location, MAX(t2.squares) squares
       FROM table t2
       GROUP BY t2.location ) t3 ON t1.location = t3.location,
     ( SELECT t4.location, MAX(t4.circles) circles
       FROM table t4
       GROUP BY t4.location ) t5 ON t1.location = t5.location
WHERE t1.squares = t3.squares
   OR t1.circles = t5.circles
```

В Access подзапросы разумно сделать статическими запросами и использовать в финальном запросе как источники данных.

Comment: location в данном случае подразумевает под собой "участок"? Сначала запросы максимумов по участкам, а далее общий запрос обьединяя по значениям?

Comment: @Dmitry Ну есссно - других кандидатов на это гордое имя как-то не наблюдается.

Comment: попробовал Ваш запрос - выдает список всех секторов которые задействованы в подчиненных запросах и заполняем все идентичными(максимальными значениями) Не работает в общем.

Comment: @Dmitry Ну не работает так не работает... не можете применить ответ - так это не моя проблема.